# How to display item label in select list when user select' any item in the list

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist, selectoption

I am new to salesforce and i had stuck with some problem i have select list when user selects any option in select list.I have to display that selected option in a output label i had use action support.But,i am getting id of that select option but i want item label so,I had tried label in select list but it didn't work please don't put low comments if i ask any wrong one i had tried some code please check it

Visual force page:

```
<apex:page controller="SelectList">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:selectList size="1" label="{!myval}">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!myoptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="one" />
</apex:selectList>
<apex:outputLabel id="one" >You have selected: {!myval}</apex:outputLabel>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller class:

```
public class SelectList {
public List<selectoption> myoptions{get;set;}
public String myval{set;get;}
public SelectList() {
myoptions=new List<selectoption>();
selectoption s1=new selectoption('fi','Jan');
selectoption s2=new selectoption('se','Feb');
selectoption s3=new selectoption('th','Mar');
myoptions.add(s1);
myoptions.add(s2);
myoptions.add(s3);
myoptions.add(new selectoption('fo','apr'));

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Label by comparing the value of `selectoption`, as shown below in findLabel method.

```
public class SelectList 
{
    public List<selectoption> myoptions{get;set;}
    public String myval{set;get;}
    public SelectList() 
    {
        myoptions=new List<selectoption>();
        selectoption s1=new selectoption('fi','Jan');
        selectoption s2=new selectoption('se','Feb');
        selectoption s3=new selectoption('th','Mar');
        myoptions.add(s1);
        myoptions.add(s2);
        myoptions.add(s3);
        myoptions.add(new selectoption('fo','apr'));

    }
}

public void findLabel()
{ 
    for (SelectOption so : myoptions)
    {
            if (so.getValue() == myval)
            {
                myval = so.getLabel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also in visualforce page `<actionsupport>` tag should call method `findLabel` as :

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!findLabel}" reRender="one" />
```

Comment: thanks,it works like a charm i got it we can create a object to selectoption  also. Thanks very much for your help @Ashwani